# argocd with cluster postgres kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am seeking information on how Argo CD can communicate with my Postgres cluster. I am concerned about potential conflicts that may arise if I use the rollback feature in Argo CD. Can anyone provide further insight and clarify if there are any conflicts that could occur? Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'd need to share the manifests you use for Postgres. What makes you think a rollback in ArgoCD would have impact? ArgoCD only communicate with K8S, not with apps deployed on it. Likely your postgres has volumes for the data. Only version of Postgres would be impacted by rollback in Argo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hey @GaëlJ im wondering if i make a roolback with argocd ! maybe the data will try to back to the old version ! thats why im asking if there is a conflict will make when i use rollback

Comment: AegoCD only rollbacks Kubernetes objects (Deployment, Service, Ingress...). Your data are not a Kibernetes object, right?

Comment: No offense but you should document yourself more on how K8s works before even considering ArgoCD.

Comment: my data in a crunchy postgres cluster that integrated with kubernetes cluster ! im certified cka so don't worry about the document